# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, java-8, mysql-8.0

I have a spring boot project running on java8 after I installed mysql8 server and tried to connect I am getting the error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed.
```

Initially I had mysql5 installed and it was working fine however when I installed mysql8 server I am getting the error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed.`.

I did use `&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` but it didn't help me much. I am just unable to proceed further and unable to connect to the database. Neither am I able to downgrade MySql to 5 again.

I am using idea intelliJ as IDE. I also tried to add the following dependency:

```
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>8.0.14</version>
```

However, none of these solutions work.

Below error is what I get when I reverted the mysql-connector-java from 8.0.14 version, however I get a similar 
error when I use the 8.0.14 version as well.
Even after changing to **MYSQL8InnoDBDialect** the problem persists.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:874) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1777) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2199) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2230) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` should work. Can you show us your application.properties (at least the JDBC URL you're using).

Comment: #server.port=8090

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lms?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: You're using the MySQL 8 driver with MySQL 8, but you're using the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`?  That doesn't sound correct? Also, please edit that information into the question itself. At the bottom of the question, you should see a link that says "edit".

Comment: Even after changing to MYSQL8InnoDBDialect the problem persists.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace you get when you use the 8.0.14 version of the MySQL connector? The stacktrace you've shown is produced by the old version of the MySQL driver.

Comment: Everything remains the same only versionn changes java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]

Answer (score 1):

You can install a client app like HeidiSQL or
another database client to solve the problem
.You should add the client option to your mysql-connector allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server. Note that AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True could allow a malicious proxy to perform a MITM attack to get the plaintext password, so it is False by default and must be explicitly enabled.

you could also try adding useSSL=false when you use it for testing/develop purposes
Just like below:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```